# How to exclude a domain from Cloudflare WARP 1.1.1.1 on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, firewall, domain, cloudflare

While using Cloudflare WARP, often when trying to upload a video on YouTube, the YouTube site asks for verification.

So to avoid this, I want to exclude youtube.com or similar domains that do not do well with Cloudflare WARP (atleast for me)

This is just one of the example. Few other sites also do not work well with it.

How to completely disable Cloudflare WARP such that it does not affect youtube.com or YouTube website at all?

Cloudflare WARP for windows 10: https://1.1.1.1/